# Project Euler 8 - Largest product in a series

Tags: python-3.x, programming-challenge

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
> greatest product  are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
> the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

This is my solution to the problem above.

```
> def largest_product_series(n, series):
>     series = str(series)
>     largest = 0
>     for i in range(0,1000-n):
>         temp = np.prod([int(series[j]) for j in range(i,n+i)])
>         largest = max(temp, largest)
>     return largest
```

I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with my code. It works just fine with n = 4. But somehow it didn't output the correct answer when n = 13.

Here's the link to the problem. [Euler 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8)

Comment: Since that's a bug, shouldn't this question go on stackoverflow? Anyway, consider that the product of 13 digits could be larger than 2 billion

Comment: Are you sure it doesn’t work? It gives the number 23514624000 which I’m reading is the correct answer.

Comment: Is the solution passing the tests on the website?

Answer (score 2):

I think your current code is working- it seems like it’s getting the same answer as other people who say they solved it (i.e. 23514624000). So I think it belongs here.

Right now, if you wanted to use this for any string of digits and any length of consecutive numbers, it would be \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity because you would have to multiply at most (length-of-series / 2) * (length-of-series / 2) numbers. Something you could use to fix that is a deque from the collections module. You could use it to know what to divide and what to multiply to get the current product, and you could also use it to track how many zeros are in the current sequence of consecutive numbers. If you do this then you only need to multiply or divide at most (length-of-series * 2) - 1 numbers, so it’s \$O(n)\$.

```py
import collections

def find_max_prod(n, series):
    
    if len(series) < n:
        return 0
        
    current_nums = collections.deque(maxlen=n)
    zero_count = 0
    max_prod = 1
    my_iter = iter(series)
    
    for _ in range(n):
        next_n = int(next(my_iter))
        max_prod *= next_n
        current_nums.append(next_n)
        if next_n == 0:
            zero_count += 1

    current_prod = max_prod if max_prod > 0 else 1
    
    for str_n in my_iter:
        n_out = current_nums.popleft()
        n_in = int(str_n)
        current_nums.append(n_in)
        if n_in == 0:
            zero_count += 1
        if n_out == 0:
            zero_count -= 1
        else:
            current_prod //= n_out
        if n_in != 0:
            current_prod *= n_in
            if current_prod > max_prod and zero_count == 0:
                max_prod = current_prod
    
    return max_prod
```

or with Toby Speight‘s suggestion:

```py
import collections

def max_of_substr(n, substr):
    current_nums = collections.deque(maxlen=n)
    my_iter = iter(substr)
    max_prod = 1
    
    for _ in range(n):
        next_n = int(next(my_iter))
        max_prod *= next_n
        current_nums.append(next_n)
    
    current_prod = max_prod

    for str_n in my_iter:
        n_out = current_nums.popleft()
        n_in = int(str_n)
        current_nums.append(n_in)
        current_prod //= n_out
        current_prod *= n_in
        if current_prod > max_prod:
            max_prod = current_prod
    
    return max_prod

def find_max_prod(n, series):
    max_substr_generator = (
        max_of_substr(n, substr)
        for substr in series.split('0')
        if len(substr) >= n
        )
    return max(max_substr_generator, default=0)
```

Comment: You can avoid counting zeros if instead you split the string on every `0` (and discard too-short substrings).  Then just test each of those substrings in turn.